Django - Request Header Fields Too Large
We use an OAuth2-Proxy for our apps. Therefore the request header includes all groups of a user and the header get large.
This is no problem for our fastAPI based apps but not for Django based apps.
We always get 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large).
Any ideas how to increase the max header value in Django?
Request Header Fields Too Large
Error parsing headers: 'limit request headers fields size' 


To resolve this issue, you can adjust the server configuration to allow larger header sizes. If you're using a web server like Nginx or Apache, you can increase the client_max_body_size or LimitRequestFieldSize respectively in their configuration files.
For Nginx, you would typically adjust the client_max_body_size directive in your server block or http block:
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 20M; # Adjust the value as needed
    ...
}

For Apache, you would adjust the LimitRequestFieldSize directive in your configuration:
LimitRequestFieldSize 81900 # Adjust the value as needed

After making these changes, remember to restart your web server for the changes to take effect. This should resolve the "Request Header Fields Too Large" error in your application.

We use gunicorn for our django apps. After adding --limit-request-field_size 16380 to the command it does work now. Thank you for pointing the right direction :)
